# visual studio 2013 c++ add path to dll

Tags: c++, dll, path

My Project needs to use DLL's provided by an SDK.
I included the path to the DLL's here:
Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment, using:

PATH=%PATH%;...path to DLL directory

In Debug all works correctly.
When I run the exe from Command Prompt, I get an error message indicating that the DLL's cannot be located.

I guess I need to also add the DLL path to another project property setting, correct?

Comment: You need to add the directory to your systems `PATH` variable.

Comment: .. or add the dlls to the directory where your executable is. Also enough answers e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/visual-studio-how-to-set-path-to-dll?rq=1)

Comment: I tried both of these .. results in same error ...SetEnvironmentVariable(L"PATH", L"%PATH%;C:\\Program Files(x86)\\......");
SetDllDirectory(L"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\.......");