# CMake linking to an import library

Tags: cmake, libmysql, import-libraries

I need to link my project to the **libmysql.dll** dynamic library (I need to do it because I'm building my project as /MDd, reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html)

Now the tricky part is that it is an **import library** (reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx) so there is a **libmysql.lib** as well.

I'm using CMake for the build:

```
set(MYSQL_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1"
    CACHE PATH "The path to the MySQL C API library")
include_directories(${MYSQL_DIR}/include)
find_library(mysql NAMES libmysql PATHS ${MYSQL_DIR}/lib)
message(STATUS "mysql library: " ${mysql})
```

CMake finds the library **libmysql.lib** but when I try to compile I get the following linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mysql.lib'
```

**mysql** as you can check above is the name of the CMake variable that contains the path to **libmysql.lib**.

I have tried to link directly to the .dll but it does not work either, CMake does not find the .dll.

#### Question

How should I proceed in CMake to link to the import library? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What your `target_link_libraries()` call looks like?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(main mysql)`, main is simply an executable from a single file main.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use result of `find_library()` call in `target_link_libraries()`. In your case it is `target_link_libraries(main ${mysql})`.

Comment: thanks @arrowd it compiles now, but when launching the program I get an error telling me that **libmysql.dll** is missing from my pc. I think I should somehow let know to CMake where to find the .dll as well.

Comment: You need to place it along your .exe file.

Comment: is there any other way to specify where to look for the dll? ideally with CMake?

Comment: It is OS loader that looks for libraries. For Windows the rules are: look in the .exe dir, look in the working dir, look in the Windows\System32 dir.

Comment: thanks @arrowd. I found another way of doing it by setting the path environment variable as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2119707/4970597