# code execution cannot proceed because cpprest_2_10.dll was not found

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, unresolved-external, lib

My aim is to use the Rest API in Visual Studio.
I downloaded the C++ tool vcpkg from https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg and followed the instructions on https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk to install cpprestsdk. That worked fine.

Then, in Visual Studio in the properties of the solution explorer, I included the following paths from the vcpkg folder into "VCC++ Directories->Include directories":

> vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master\buildtrees\cpprestsdk\src\v2.10.2-718a4e55e9\Release\include\cpprest
>
> vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master\buildtrees\cpprestsdk\src\v2.10.2-718a4e55e9\Release\include
>
> vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master\buildtrees\cpprestsdk\src\v2.10.2-718a4e55e9\Release\include\pplx

Then I run my code and the following errors occur:

`LNK2001 unresolved external symbols` (32 errors like this)

I googled it and was told to include the respective ".lib"-files into "Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies" and to include the paths of the corresponding ".dll"-files into "Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories", what I did.

Now, running the code again, just the following error occurs:

`code execution cannot proceed because cpprest_2_10.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem`,

although the "cpprest_2_10.dll" is in the path, which I included previously.

I have no idea what the problem is. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 9):

Try to put the missing dll file right to the directory of your compiled exe.

Or check this answer to set a path so your binary can find the dll file:

[How do I set the path to a DLL file in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/how-do-i-set-the-path-to-a-dll-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I can confirm that placing the missing dll in the same directory as the exe works. I was following this C++ to .dll tutorial at https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/08/use-cmake-to-help-build-and-use-windows.htmlvisual