# c# front-end GUI calling linux C++ functions

Tags: c#, c++, linux

I am working on a project that the software is written in .NET C# and now new features require that we call third party's APIs that are built in C++ on Linux.  We are given the .so files.  What is the best way to achieve this?  Is developing a JBoss application server and with JNI the best way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Mono Interop](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Librarieshttp://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) and an ASP.NET web service implemented in Mono

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply a web service façade for the C# application? This way you'll call the APIs through Web References. JNI will add a whole Java framework between your app and the APIs.

---

Also, consider reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710465/reference-a-gnu-c-dll-built-in-gcc-against-cygwin-from-c-net).