# Use Cygwin compiled dll from windows

Tags: c++, c, dll, cygwin

I need to use cygwin compiled dll from visual studio C++ or Code:blocks MinGW.

I tried use this simple example

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int  MyFunc()
{
    printf("Printed from cygwin dll");
    return 0;
}
```

And this makefile

```
obj = mydll.o   
ALLLIBS = \
    mydll.a \
    mydll.dll

all: $(ALLLIBS)

mydll.a: $(obj)
    $(LINK.a)

mydll.dll: $(obj)
    $(cygTest.dll)


cygTest.dll     = gcc -shared -o cygTest.dll \
    -Wl,--out-implib \
    -Wl,--export-all-symbols \
    -Wl,--enable-auto-import \
    -Wl,--whole-archive $(obj) \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive 

mydll.a = ar $(ARFLAGS) $@ $%
```

I am trying to call the final dll here.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef int(*FnP_MyFunc)();
typedef void(*FnP_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT)();

int main()
{
    FnP_MyFunc fnMyFunc;
    HMODULE hLib, hGetCygwinIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\cygwin1.dll"));
    if (hGetCygwinIDDLL)
    {
        FnP_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT init = (FnP_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT)GetProcAddress(hGetCygwinIDDLL, "cygwin_dll_init");
        init();
        std::cout << "init complete " << endl;
    }
    int a;
    hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\cygwin64\\home\\azatyan\\TestDynamicLink\\cygTest.dll"));
    if (hLib)
    {
        std::cout << "From wrapper dll  " << std::endl;
        fnMyFunc = (FnP_MyFunc)GetProcAddress(hLib, "MyFunc");
        a = fnMyFunc();         
        cout << a;

    }
    FreeLibrary(hGetCygwinIDDLL);
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    return 0;
}
```

And it just hangs when it reaches to my MyFunc function. Or exits with code 1536.. 
Can anybody help me, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**  I have tried the same without `printf()` function, worked ok, returned expected value, this means that the problem is in dependency libraries, but still I don't know haw I can add all dependency libraries..

Comment: maybe the problem is here ? 

Q: Can I link with both MSVCRT*.DLL and cygwin1.dll?
A:No, you must use one or the other, they are mutually exclusive.

[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787344/using-dll-compiled-with-cygwin-inside-visual-studio-2010)
Does anybody knows ?