# Visual Studio 2008: Use external Debug-DLL for Debug-Run and external Release-DLL for Release-Run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, configuration

**Short version:**
If running a program from VS2008 in Release mode, I want it to use 
`pathA\externaldll.dll`.
If running a program from VS2008 in Debug mode, I want it to use 
`pathB\externaldll.dll`

**Long version:**
I have a programm that is linked against external dll-files (VTK). I have built the external application myself in both Debug and Release mode. The external dll-files are located like this:

```
<some path>\Debug\externalDll.dll
<some path>\Release\externalDll.dll
```

(so they are called the same, but have different folders).

I want to step into the external code for Debug Builds, but I want the Release Builds to use the Release DLLs for testing the execution time (I process big datasets).

Linking to the according dlls is easy, as I have project settings for that. But when executing, Visual Studio takes the first dll it finds within the PATH environment variable.

**Cumbersome solution idea:**
Having the PATH variable like: PATH=;%CURRENTDLLPATH%;
and setting CURRENTDLLPATH in a post-build-step.
Is there no solution built-in into VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a built-in and easy way:

The "Environment"-Variable within "project settings"/Debugging.

So setting the Environment-Variable to

```
PATH=C:\Paraview\ParaView-3.8.0\gen\bin\$(ConfigurationName);%PATH%
```

for the project to be exectued does the trick.

The question was answered several times here, I just didn't find it
(e.g. [How do I set a path in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428085/how-do-i-set-a-path-in-visual-studio))

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give different file names to the external Dlls in Debug and in Release, and add both directories to the PATH?

Comment: Because renaming the resulting dll-files won't do the trick (as the .lib-Files point to the old file-names) and the external application uses a build-system I am not very familiar with (Cmake). I'd had to dig deeply into the external build system to find and rename all the external dll build-targets according to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a build step to copy the correct DLL to the folder in PATH, and make different build steps in Debug and Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your debug build output files should go to a `./debug` folder and your release output files should go to a `./release` folder.

You should copy the appropriate external DLL file into this output folder: Use a pre-build step and use the VS macro `$(ConfigurationName)` to refer to debug/release.