# "opencv_world454.dll was not found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

hello I had imported OpenCV into my C++ project but for some reason my code gives me this error.

CODE:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string path = "Resources/test.png";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path);
    imshow("Image", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

error:

[image]

I think it might be because of my paths but I'm not sure I think I got them right.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dicfz.png)

Edit: I reinstalled the setup and installed openCV in a new path and now I do have `.dll` files but it keeps giving me an error here are new screenshots
[image]
[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: None of the pictures show the existence of the dll file that your OS says it did not find. The required dlls should be placed in one of the folders of the `PATH` environment variable or the same folder as your executable. This Microsoft  document describes how and where the OS will search for the dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: Avoid putting dlls in the OS system folders.

Comment: Your bottom picture is `pdb` files. They are synbol files that can be used to help debug the opencv code (if you want to look inside the code when you are debugging your code) but these are not what the OS needs to run your program. It needs the `.dll` files.

Comment: The problem is that even with a reinstall it doesn't download `.dll` files

Comment: You may want to check the install folder for the dlls. Perhaps the installation did not add the folder containing the dlls to your OS `PATH`  environment variable requiring you to do that yourself.

Comment: I did add `PATH` manually.

Comment: If you logged out and back in after adjusting the `PATH` environment variable and verified that the dlls are in the folder that you added to the `PATH` my guess is you made some type of typing mistake. Also note that `opencv_world454.dll` is a different dll from the one in the picture. `opencv_world454.dll` is the release version of the dll `opencv_world454d.dll` is the debug version. You need debug dlls to run your debug configuration and release dlls to run your release application.

Comment: it looks like I don't have `.dll` installed for some reason does anyone know where I can get them and where should I put them?

Comment: You can compile opencv yourself if you build from source. Or you can use vcpkg to build it for you. Both options require installing CMake. The simpler option would be to use vcpkg as everything is automatic after you get vcpkg setup.

Comment: Related to vcpkg building: [https://eximia.co/hello-opencv-with-c-using-visual-studio-2017-and-vcpkg/](https://eximia.co/hello-opencv-with-c-using-visual-studio-2017-and-vcpkg/) note that all of the commands that start with a . should be .\ instead of . I assume the web formatting lost the \ for some reason

Comment: I just downloaded [https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.5.4/opencv-4.5.4-vc14_vc15.exe/download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.5.4/opencv-4.5.4-vc14_vc15.exe/download) and ran the installer and it has the required dlls in the `opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin` or `opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin` folder. If you are using this same download perhaps your problem is your antivirus deleting the dlls.

Comment: Here is an image of the folder contents: [https://pasteboard.co/ma8BExBDHZcB.png](https://pasteboard.co/ma8BExBDHZcB.png)

Comment: okay I reinstalled a setup and installed it in a new path I do have `.dll` files but it still gives me an error give me a min I would edit a post

Comment: I don't think you are setting the PATH correctly. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428085/how-do-i-set-a-path-in-visual-studio/2916103#2916103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428085/how-do-i-set-a-path-in-visual-studio/2916103#2916103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install a new setup and install OpenCV into another path not sure why it helped but still thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it will help someone
Instructions:

1. Open Project->Property
2. Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment
3. `PATH=C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin`;

You need your path to the folder

Comment: I am still facing this issue with visual studio 2022. I have added "include path" in the C/C++.And additional libraries and additional dependencies path in linker setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2022 and I had the same issue. The steps to solve the issue to me were:

1. Tap Win+I to open Settings
2. Go to System->About
3. Under "Device Specification" click on "Advanced system settings"
4. Under "System properties" click on "Environment Variables..."
5. In the section that holds the user variables click on "Path" and then click on "Edit"
6. In the "Edit environment variable" tab click on "New"
7. Type the path to your opencv installation folder that has the .dll file, for example, for me the path is C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc16\bin
8. Click "Ok" to confirm and close all the opened tabs

NOTE: when I added the path to opencv bin folder to the SYSTEM Path variable it did not work for some reason, but when I added it to the USER Path variable it worked.

Now try to hit F5 inside Visual Studio to build and run in Debug mode.
To me, this solution worked like a charm. Hope it works for you guys as well!