# Unable to solve includePath error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include-path

I'm unable to use standard libraries while writing a C program. I'm a novice. Help will be appreciated.
[Error depiction image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vm5J.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428085/how-do-i-set-a-path-in-visual-studio) help?

Comment: have you read the VSC C/C++ doc pages, perform the example to the key press