# The code execution cannot proceed because python37.dll was not found

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, path

I have a piece of code in C++ into which I am trying to include the Python.h library in order to manage the GIL (to speed things up). Despite adding the proper includes, libraries and path addresses (I am using Visual Studio 2019), I still obtain the following error message:

[image: error_message]

As far as I know, I correctly added the address of the DLL in the $PATH for this project, as shown:

[image: project_properties]

What am I forgetting here?

Comment: This question might help: [How do I set a path in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428085/how-do-i-set-a-path-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Does dragging the dll into the VS project folder resolve this?

Comment: @ZWang: that worked, although I wish I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this program in release mode? After switching from debug to release, the project properties of debug mode will not be inherited, so it is necessary to reset the project properties.

You could also try to place the dll file in the .exe directory or write the dll path into the project properties.

At the same time, it is also necessary to check whether the dll file is accidentally deleted by the antivirus software.

Comment: I made sure that the project properties applied to all configurations, yet that didn't work. Copying the .dll into the VS project folder actually fixed it.

Comment: @patrick2016  Yes, I mentioned the method in the second sentence.