# DLL directories used in debug mode on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have dlls in some directory (lets name it "ExternalDllDir"). And I built my C++ console app used that dlls.
I use
set path=F:\pathes\ExternalDllDir;%path%
to launch my console app from cmd. It works fine.

So, now I need to launch my console app in debug mode from Visual Studio (by F5). But I can't make some settings in project options for Visual Studio to find external dll dir.

So how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916103/4165552 - this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That works for me
Project Properties -> Debugging -> Environment
PATH=F:\pathes\ExternalDllDir;%PATH%