# Nunit test setup method with argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Can we have a test set up method with arguments?
I need a different set up for every test in a fixture.

Do we have something (or similar way) as the hypothetical idea :

```
[SetUp]
[Argument("value-1")]
[Argument("value-2")]
[Argument("value-3")]
public void InitializeTest(string value)
{
    //set env var with value
}
```

Comment: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5.5

Comment: It's not clear why you'd try to parameterize the *setup* rather than the *test*.

Comment: after this setup the tests do the same job. it probably makes more sense to take this bit into the test and make the test parametrized!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Setup* is executed once per each tests and for one tests there is only one SetUp and TearDown. You can call your Initialize method from tests explicitly and then create Data-Driven tests using `TestCase` attribute

```
public void InitializeTest(string value)
{
    //set env var with value
}

[TestCase("Value-1")]
[TestCase("Value-2")]
[TestCase("Value-3")]
public void Test(string value)
{
    InitializeTest(value);

    //Arange
    //Act
    //Assert
}
```

As result, you will have three tests each calling `InitializeTest` with different parameters

Answer (score 47):

It can be done using the TestFixture attribute with a parameter.

If all the tests in the class depend on the same parameter this is the way to go.

The class will need a constructor with the same parameter passed to the TestFixture attribute.

See Parameterized Test Fixtures on https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute

```
[TestFixture("Oscar")]
[TestFixture("Paul")]
[TestFixture("Peter")]
public class NameTest
{
    private string _name;

    public NameTest(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_something_that_depends_on_name()
    {
        //Todo...
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_something_that_also_depends_on_name()
    {
        //Todo...
    }
    //...
}
```

This code is from the nunit documentation website:

```
[TestFixture("hello", "hello", "goodbye")]
[TestFixture("zip", "zip")]
[TestFixture(42, 42, 99)]
public class ParameterizedTestFixture
{
    private readonly string eq1;
    private readonly string eq2;
    private readonly string neq;

    public ParameterizedTestFixture(string eq1, string eq2, string neq)
    {
        this.eq1 = eq1;
        this.eq2 = eq2;
        this.neq = neq;
    }

    public ParameterizedTestFixture(string eq1, string eq2)
        : this(eq1, eq2, null)
    {
    }

    public ParameterizedTestFixture(int eq1, int eq2, int neq)
    {
        this.eq1 = eq1.ToString();
        this.eq2 = eq2.ToString();
        this.neq = neq.ToString();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestEquality()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(eq1, eq2);
        if (eq1 != null && eq2 != null)
            Assert.AreEqual(eq1.GetHashCode(), eq2.GetHashCode());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestInequality()
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(eq1, neq);
        if (eq1 != null && neq != null)
            Assert.AreNotEqual(eq1.GetHashCode(), neq.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup method is used to do some preTest jobs, which would include preparing for the test like setting any values needed for the test to run, you can set these inside the setup method instead of providing the values as parameters.