# How do I set PATH variable in Visual Studio's cmake project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, development-environment

I'm using VS 2019 to compile a qt project. The compilation runs well, but when I start the executable, I'm getting error messages about missing Qt dlls. I understand this is fixed with adding path to the dlls to the PATH environment variable, but in VS normal project, you can [modify program starting environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419979/setting-environment-variables-in-pre-build-event-and-using-in-compilation-step#420011) so that you don't have to make the modifications system-wide.
This works for VS normal projects, but how do I make it work for cmake projects?

Comment: I would use the native MSVS format "NMake" (in preference to "CMake") if at all possible!

Comment: You don't really do this at the CMake stage, although I expect you could generate a .user file that Visual Studio could apply. In my usage I use CMake scripting to copy the .dlls in the same folder as the executable

Comment: @drescherjm I know the issue as well as the solutions with copying the DLLs or manually editing the generated project but _although I expect you could generate a .user file that Visual Studio could apply_  That's an idea I was not aware of: just write a CMake function which patches (or adds something to) the generated VS solution / project. If you could demonstrate this in an answer I would consider this as _valuable_. ;-)